# Multiple installation of device, the windows xp shows the error code 28

Tags: windows, driver, device-driver, routines

I have created the driver for our device and installed in windows xp. While installing first time it will install successfully and shows in windows driver list. But when again install  the windows xp shows that error code 28 and in driver list is showing that unknown device.

Please note that the multiple time installation done in windows 7, windows 8 successfully, but only create the problem in windows xp.

Any idea?

Comment: Why are you using windows xp? that is the question.

Comment: Testing purpose I am using windows xp.

Comment: Please provide more information - what kind of driver is this? Have you looked at the setupapi.log? Do you have source code for the driver? Have you tried adding some logging or hooking up a debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heap memory was not free properly. Deleted the memory properly that is working in all platform.